# showing multiple shockwave flash swf in wpf vb.net blend

Tags: wpf, vb.net, flash, blend

i'm totally new with vb.net and wpf and i'm trying to show multiple .swf file in a wpf program that i'm writing with blend.is it possible to use a single webview to show multiple swf files?i mean placing like 5 buttons near that webview and by clicking each button, a specific .swf file appear in the webview?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps

1.Copy te swf file in bin folder.

2.Select "Add/Remove Items".

3.Select "COM Components" Select "Shockwave Flash Object". Click OK.

4.You can see the Shockwave Flash Object in the tool bar.

Code:

```
AxShockwaveFlash1.Movie = Application.StartupPath & "\flashfile.swf"
AxShockwaveFlash1.Play()
```

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_add_swf_file_in_vb.net_forms_which_is_save_in_resources#ixzz1toABaXKF

SWF Object Project if you like to see:

https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/